# How to create a role and a database with kubectl and the chart of postgresql?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have just installed the chart of postgresql and now I need a kubectl script to create the role and the database. In psql I use this script:

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres <<EOF
CREATE ROLE aaa WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'bbb';
CREATE DATABASE ccc OWNER aaa;
EOF
```

But how can I do this with kubectl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use kubectl exec to run this command within the postgres container:

The flag `-i` opens a terminal in the container so you can see the command output.

```
kubectl exec -i postgres-pod -- psql -d postgres -U postgres  <<EOF
CREATE ROLE aaa WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'bbb';
CREATE DATABASE ccc OWNER aaa;
EOF
```